# Resources for teaching algebraic fractions to a dyscalculic pupil

Tags: secondary-education, algebra, fractions, dyscalculia

I have a new student in math class (high school) since last month, and she's being diagnosed with dyslexia and dyscalculia. We are about to go into conic sections and she should be able to do some basic algebraic manipulation like $1/x + x$, but she says that she cannot do it because of her problem. I don't know how to help her and she is  not able to explicitate her difficulty... any help?

Comment: definitely not an answer, but I know that students with dyscalculia have an INCREDIBLY hard time with anything involving numbers, even things like reading a clock, counting change, or even ordering numbers from largest to smallest.  I would suggest finding additional supports in your school who would know better how to work with a dyscalculic student who could maybe spend time outside of class or push into your class.  In my experience with the few dyscalculic students I have had, basic algebraic manipulation was unfortunately a very far way away from where they were mathematically.

Comment: Actually algebraic manipulation, as far as I know, is sometimes easier than dealing with numbers because it relates more to logical reasoning than to arithmetical facts. But I'm no psychologist.